# /dev/sdb1 partition full but /dev/sda empty

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk-usage

I am new to Ubuntu and I tried to download recently a large file, but it stopped because it said the disk was full, even though I'm supposed to have almost 1Tb of disk space. I tried to look at partitions and I saw (using `df -h` and looking for the '/') that Ubuntu seems to be mounted on `/dev/sdb2` and that it had only 24Gb of remaining space.

```
antoine@hp:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  2,2M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb2       117G   88G   24G  79% /
tmpfs           7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

GParted software however shows that `/dev/sda1` has more than  800Gb of free space.

[image: see GParted screenshot]

Comment: Looks like you are not using, nor have mounted that sda1 partition. You can move /home to it, or just move data in /home, but not /home's hidden settings to the data partition. Or some of the data. Have good backups, before any major change. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving  or Data https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community! Can you also share the output of `sudo lsblk`? It looks to me like you have installed Ubuntu on a 128GB disk (sdb, with sdb2 being the second partition of that). Therefore /dev/sdb2 is mounted on /, being your root file system.

Comment: Thank you very much @oldfred! I followed [your recommendation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk) and it is working well now